# How to Get Body of email from Pipe to program

Tags: php, html, email-headers

I am piping an email to a program and running some code.

**

### I know how to get the "From:" and the "Subject:" but how do I get only the body of the email?

**

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?

$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while (!feof($fd)) {
  $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

$lines = explode("\n", $email);

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) 
{


    // look out for special headers
    if (preg_match("/Subject:/", $lines[$i], $matches)) 
        {

    list($One,$Subject) = explode("Subject:", $lines[$i]);    
    list($Subject,$Gone) = explode("<", $Subject);  


        }
```

etc... HOW DO I GET THE BODY CONTENT OF THE EMAIL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you want where the headers end, and to know if it's multipart or not so you can get the right portion(s) of the email.

Here is some information:

[parsing raw email in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896/parsing-raw-email-in-php)

Which says that the first double newline should be the beginning of the body of the email.

This page might give you some other ideas (see script below):

http://thedrupalblog.com/configuring-server-parse-email-php-script

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

// fetch data from stdin
$data = file_get_contents("php://stdin");

// extract the body
// NOTE: a properly formatted email's first empty line defines the separation between the headers and the message body
list($data, $body) = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);

// explode on new line
$data = explode("\n", $data);

// define a variable map of known headers
$patterns = array(
  'Return-Path',
  'X-Original-To',
  'Delivered-To',
  'Received',
  'To',
  'Message-Id',
  'Date',
  'From',
  'Subject',
);

// define a variable to hold parsed headers
$headers = array();

// loop through data
foreach ($data as $data_line) {

  // for each line, assume a match does not exist yet
  $pattern_match_exists = false;

  // check for lines that start with white space
  // NOTE: if a line starts with a white space, it signifies a continuation of the previous header
  if ((substr($data_line,0,1)==' ' || substr($data_line,0,1)=="\t") && $last_match) {

    // append to last header
    $headers[$last_match][] = $data_line;
    continue;

  }

  // loop through patterns
  foreach ($patterns as $key => $pattern) {

    // create preg regex
    $preg_pattern = '/^' . $pattern .': (.*)$/';

    // execute preg
    preg_match($preg_pattern, $data_line, $matches);

    // check if preg matches exist
    if (count($matches)) {

      $headers[$pattern][] = $matches[1];
      $pattern_match_exists = true;
      $last_match = $pattern;

    }

  }

  // check if a pattern did not match for this line
  if (!$pattern_match_exists) {
    $headers['UNMATCHED'][] = $data_line;
  }

}

?>
```

**EDIT**

Here is a PHP extension called MailParse:

http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse

Somebody has built a class around it called MimeMailParse:

http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

And here is a blog entry discussing how to use it:

http://www.bucabay.com/web-development/a-php-mime-mail-parser-using-mailparse-extension/

Comment: Wow... you are so fast. I am not sure I understand this yet. What do I Var do I echo out to get access to the Body then? :)

Comment: I noticed it works for html emails but if you send from Gmail you get this:

Comment: --90e6ba1efd480d5bc804a150689a Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 MY CONTENT I SENT --90e6ba1efd480d5bc804a150689a Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 MY CONTENT I SENT 
--90e6ba1efd480d5bc804a150689a--

Comment: Those are content-type boundaries. Essentially, it's sending two different versions of the email, text and html (for different email clients that may not support html), and uses the `--90e6ba1efd480d5bc804a150689a` to 'demarcate' or mark a 'boundary' where one message block starts and stops. This is also how attachments are included (as text) within the message packets.

Comment: You should also see in Gmail's See Original the line: `Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----=90e6ba1efd480d5bc804a150689a"`, with the part between the parentheses a randomly-generated string meant to be one-use (for the most part).

Comment: Sorry I am still working on this problem. Is there a php code to get both types of content? The html and the text? I have worked for hours on this.

Comment: @vizenor - Give this a shot: http://www.bucabay.com/web-development/a-php-mime-mail-parser-using-mailparse-extension/